# How to add pipenv to the PATH in my .zshrc

Tags: python, zsh, pipenv, zshrc

I'm trying to work with pipenv and I installed it using pip, however whenever I run any command starting with `pipenv`, I get the following error:

```
zsh: command not found: pipenv
```

I know I should add it to my path somehow but I'm not entirely familiar with how to configure my `~/.zshrc`.

Also, I tried locating where `pipenv` is located using `where pipenv`, but I get

```
pipenv not found
```

Comment: How did you install pipenv?

Comment: @AnthonySottile `sudo -H pip install -U pipenv` I also tried `pip install pipenv`. Side note, pip=pip3 in my case. I have an alias for it in my zshrc file.

Comment: `sudo pip install --user`, oh dear -- the `--user` flag is designed to not use root.  You probably just want to `pip install --user` and then it'll end up in `~/.local/bin` or something of the sort and you can put that on your `PATH`

Comment: @AnthonySottile that cleared it up for me. Thank you so much! If you don't mind, what's the difference between using `sudo pip install --user` and just using `pip install --user`?

Comment: the first does a user installation for the root user, which is mostly nonsensical (probably wrote to `/root/.local/`)

Comment: Since `which` *uses* `PATH` to find its argument, it's not useful for finding a program not already found via `PATH`.

Comment: Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 13):

You will need to add support to your ~/.zshrc file. You can access it with `code ~/.zshrc`.

I needed to add these to the file:

```sh
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHON_BIN_PATH="$(python3 -m site --user-base)/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$PYTHON_BIN_PATH"
```

Once you add them you will need to restart your terminal before you can see these changes take effect.

Answer (score 4):

#### Using `pip`

`pipenv` should be in your PATH if you installed it using `pip` as a [user install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs), as recommended [in the docs](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/install/#pragmatic-installation-of-pipenv):

```sh
pip install --user pipenv
```

If it still isn't available, you'll need to add the user base's binary directory to your PATH:

- **UNIX** default: `~/.local`
- **MacOS** Framework builds: `~/Library/Python/X.Y`
- **Windows**: `%APPDATA%\Python`

You can read more about this in the Python docs on [`site.USER_BASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE).

#### Using Homebrew

If you're using Homebrew, then another option is to install `pipenv` like so:

```sh
brew install pipenv
```

This installs it globally. Since `pipenv` can manage even different python versions via `pyenv`, it's preferable to have it set up like this instead of installing it only for a specific python version using `pip`.

However, this method is **discouraged** according to the `pipenv` [documentation](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/install/#homebrew-installation-of-pipenv-discouraged):

> Homebrew installation is discouraged because each time the Homebrew Python is upgraded, which Pipenv depends on, users have to re-install Pipenv, and perhaps all virtual environments managed by it.

Comment: Relative n00b here, trying to use Pipenv for the first time, and on Mac.  Seemed to me that the docs explicitly suggest that installing via brew is discouraged.  

See: https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/install/#homebrew-installation-of-pipenv-discouraged

Comment: Thanks! Good point, I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: after `brew install pipenv` it says "pyenv: pipenv: command not found"

Comment: or using `pip install --user pipenv`

Answer (score 0):

Open `~/.zshrc` and append these lines:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

or:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.9
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I tested it on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Use a package manager such as apt, yum or brew to install pipenv.

Installing pipenv with a package manager rather than pip adds it directly to `$PATH` of any shell, like bash or zsh.

```
sudo apt install pipenv
```